# Why is an ADO connection still creating an "ldb" lock file even when read-only?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, locking, ado

Quick question for you database experts. See the following code (VBA/ADO), called from Excel:

```
Dim DBPath As String, ConnStr As String
DBPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Database.mdb"
ConnStr = "Data Source=" & DBPath & ";" & "Jet OLEDB:Database Password=" & DBPass()
Dim cnn as ADODB.Connection
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
With cnn
    .Provider = CheckProvider(strPath:=DBPath) ' Separate function call. Ignore
    .Mode = adModeRead
    .Open ConnStr
End With
Stop ' To inspect the directory...
```

It *should* open the database as read-only, given the "adModeRead" specification. However I have noticed that a lock file (Database.ldb) is still being created/deleted in the directory while the connection is active. Surely this goes contrary to the read-only command, which should mean that no data may be written, and therefore no file lock is needed.

Can anyone explain what's happening here? Thanks.

Edit: And a follow-up - if I wanted to open the connection as purely read-only without creating any lock file, is there any other method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lock file records connections to the db file.  That information is important in a multi-user context.  Even if yours is the only connection and is intentionally read-only, Access still records that connection in the lock file.  It would be important in a situation where another used wanted to connect to the same db file in exclusive mode in order to make design changes --- they would not be allowed exclusive access while your connection is still active.

Comment: Thanks - but I'm wondering why a read-only connection would affect the ability of another user to make changes. Surely that's what read-only means, right?

To add context: I am the sole designer of the document, and database connection are short, and only made via VBA. No-one connects to the DB and leaves it open. I have an Excel Workbook_Open event that loads data, then when the user makes changes short connections are made to write data. I just don't want someone to be prevented from writing because another user is in the process of loading the initial data (which takes a few seconds).

Comment: Sorry, I totally misunderstood the question.  I thought it was simply about why a lock file is created for a read-only connection.  Please consider revising the question to clarify what you're really after.  Then I can delete this answer.

Comment: Oh, your answer is very interesting - and appreciated! It does indeed address the question I asked. It was just an implied secondary question about whether there's anything else I can do to prevent the lock. I did not ask that originally because I wasn't sure if this behaviour was an error or not. I have now added the secondary question as a comment.

Comment: OK.  As best I recall, ADO connections permitting shared access were tricky.  But I can't offer details because I largely abandoned ADO in favor of DAO.  I still think you should revise the question to clarify your aims and maybe someone else can step in with the solution you need.

Comment: Hmm.  Do you get what you want with `.Mode=adModeShareDenyNone` or `.Mode=adModeRead+adModeShareDenyNone`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Just tried them both, but the .ldb file still appears! Thanks anyway.